# Show a system is almost linear near the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the system

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x'(t) &= \sin(y-3x) \\ 
y'(t) &= \cos x-e^y
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

is almost linear about the origin. The method I know to apply is discard any nonlinear terms and consider the corresponding linear system, then to find the critical points of that system. However doing that in this case would leave

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x'(t) &= 0 \\ 
y'(t) &= 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

which does not have a single critical point at the origin, every value of $t$ is a critical point.

Comment: What does it mean for a system of differential equations to be “almost linear”?

Comment: @aghostinthefigures:  I'm curious about that meself!

Comment: If you apply the Taylor expansions of the elementary functions, you will find non-zero constant and linear terms. For instance $\sin(u)=u+O(u^3)$.